# Passing data from JDialog to frame by customize button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jdialog

I am new in swing with jdialog, I have searched throughout but I can't seem to find a solution which is using the custom button. The only solution I found was using their inbuilt input JDialog. But that doesn't solve my issue.

I am trying to pass data(from Dialog texfield "hello" to parent frame textField after clicking save)  but unable to do so.

Did anybody face the same issue? 
Any help?

[image]

```
public class dataparse {

  String result;
  String inputValue;

public void mainFrame() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(" Parent Frame ");
    JPanel center = new JPanel();
    JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
    // JLabel data = new JLabel("data is...");
    JTextField text = new JTextField();

    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    center.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    center.add(text);
    center.add(enter);
    frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            confirmDialog();
            text.setText(inputValue);

        }
    });

    frame.setVisible(true);

}


    private void confirmDialog(){
        JTextField output = new JTextField("Hellloooo");
        JButton save = new JButton("Save");


          JDialog customDialog = new JDialog();
          Container pane = customDialog.getContentPane();
          pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

          pane.add(new JLabel("Startubg"));
          pane.add(output);
          pane.add(save);

          customDialog.setSize(300,400);

          customDialog.add(output);
          customDialog.add(save);

          customDialog.setVisible(true);

          save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                result = output.getText();
            }
        });

    }
```

Thank you in advance :)

For an instance i have 2 classes and i want the second class to call dialog.dispose() from the first class. but i am unable to call the method, any ideas

**main.java**

```
public JDialog dialogBox(){

    //JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Date picker", true);
    dialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            dialog = new JDialog(frame,"Date picker " , true);
            DatePicker_Demo picker = new DatePicker_Demo();
            dialog.setSize(500, 300);
            dialog.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
            dialog.add(new DatePicker_Demo().addBtn());
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    return dialog;
}
```

**second.java**

```
public JButton addBtn(){
    JButton btn = new AddBills().exitBtn();
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new AddBills().dialogBox().dispose();
        }
    });

    return btn;
}
```

Comment: In the dialog you setting text field's value to 'result' variable. But in the `JFrame`, you are using variable `inputValue` in `text.setText(inputValue);`. Is that a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with putting the text.setText part inside the actionListener of your "Save" button ?

eg

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       result = output.getText();
       text.setText(result);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField txtField;
private JButton btnSave;
private static Window frame2; // making it static so i can work on it from main()
private static int num = 500;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Window frame1 = new Window();
                frame2 = new Window();
                frame1.setVisible(true);
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                frame2.txtField.setText("");// clear the text box of window 2
                frame2.setTitle("window 2");
                frame2.btnSave.setVisible(false); // won't see button on window 2
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Window() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100 + num, 100, 506, 514);
    setTitle("window1");
    num += num; // so you can see both windows
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    txtField = new JTextField();
    txtField.setText("Hello");
    txtField.setBounds(39, 151, 376, 117);
    contentPane.add(txtField);
    txtField.setColumns(10);

    btnSave = new JButton("save");
    btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String text = txtField.getText(); // get the text after save button was clicked.
            txtField.setText("");// clear textfield of window 1.
            frame2.txtField.setText(text); // set the text on textField of window 2
            setVisible(true); // update
            frame2.setVisible(true); // update
        }
    });
    btnSave.setBounds(169, 302, 115, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnSave);
    }
}
```

Of course you can make it more OOP but i wanted to keep it simple in one form so you can see it all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like in below example. I think the important line you are missing in your code is `setModal(true);`.

Without `setModal(true);` line, execution will directly go from `confirmDialog();` to `text.setText(inputValue);` without waiting for user to enter a text in the dialog.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class InputDialogExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel label = new JLabel();

    JButton openDialogButton = new JButton("Open Dialog");
    openDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog(frame);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        label.setText(dialog.getValue());
      }
    });

    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
    frame.getContentPane().add(openDialogButton);
    frame.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class CustomDialog extends JDialog {

  private String value;

  CustomDialog(Frame owner) {

    super(owner, "Dialog");

    setModal(true); // This is the important line

    JTextField textField = new JTextField();

    JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
    okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        value = textField.getText();
        setVisible(false);
      }
    });

    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    getContentPane().add(textField);
    getContentPane().add(okButton);
    setBounds(500, 400, 300, 200);
  }

  String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: For an example, in my main class first.java , i write a method to display Jdialog but i am accessing Jbutton from a different class which is in second.java to add in my dialog in my first class. is it possible for me to kill the JDialog from a second.java class?

Comment: @FaridAvesko, is this first.java and second.java code different from the code in the question? If so, please post that actual code in the question. As I've mentioned in my answer, I think `dialog.setModal(true);` is the missing part in your code. Without this line, program execution will NOT wait till user enters a text in the dialog.

Comment: Yea, i have updated the question, i understand the part that you wrote. but now i cant seem to call the function if i created a new button in different class

Comment: @FaridAvesko, you have to write the code more "object oriented". And you have to understand the execution flow. When user clicks `btn` in second.java, an `AddBills` object is created. Then, `dialogBox()` method is called. Inside `dialogBox()` method, an `ActionListener` is added to `dialogButton`. Then `dialog` is returned. (Note that code inside `actionPerformed()` is not executed. That code is executed only when `dialogButton` is clicked. So, may be `dialog` is `null`.) Then, on that returned `dialog` object (which may be `null`), `dispose()` is called.